# Share data(not /home) partition between two linux OS Fedora and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a 1 TB of hdd space. I have hard wiped my hdd and removed windows10 OS as I wish to install Ubuntu 20.04 and fedora 32 in 400 GB at the beginning of the 1 TB free space and use the rest of the free space as a shared data partition for storing programs so that I can work on any program in linux of my choice. 
I was thinking to go for a NTFS data partition. Would it be a good idea since I have removed windows?. Also, suggest me if there is any better way of doing things.
Secondly, Please help in partitioning the hdd appropriately. Would I need a diff swap for fedora or can I use the swap already made for Ubuntu. Any other suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Too bad you wiped Windows 10. You really needed it to 1) run Windows-only apps, 2) do BIOS and firmware updates. To your question... with Windows, NTFS would have been a good choice. With just Linux, ext4 might be a better choice.

Comment: sir Windows was to irritating thus I went for a complete linux system... a frest start. Secondly I wanted to know wheter ext4 would be identified by both fedora and ubuntu. Would I require another swap partition for fedora? Can't it just use the ubuntu's swap partition?

Comment: I don't know if Fedora uses ext4 or not. I don't support Fedora. I wouldn't share a swap partition... however you can use a /swapfile (the default in 20.04), instead of a physical partition, in Ubuntu, and then create whatever kind of swap file/partition that Fedora supports.